# showing Java app splash screen with MANIFEST.MF; is there a way to set minimum on screen time?

Tags: java, splash-screen

I have a Java desktop application in a runnable JAR file.  I'm using the MANIFEST.MF file to display a splash screen like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: MyApp
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif
```

It works but the splash image is only on screen for a fraction of a second which is too short a time.

Is there a way for me to set the minimum display time for the splash screen?  I'd like it to be onscreen for minimum 2 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can change the amount of time that image will be shown.

What you could do is to just create your own implementation of a splash screen.
Basically all you need is a `Window` that displays one image and that loads the rest of your app in the background. When the app has finished loading and more than 2 seconds have passed you can hide the splash and display your main app.

Comment: +1 for `Window` as opposed to any Swing class.  The best splashes are all pure AWT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I thought the idea of using the image in the MANIFEST.MF was that the VM was able to put the image onscreen before your application was loaded so the splash screen would appear faster?  Using your solution, wouldn't the image appear only after the runnable app is loaded into memory?

Comment: @RobertHume The java `ClassLoader` will only load as many classes as absolutely necessary for your application to run. So by calling your splash screen implementation first you will run into very low loading times. Then when you invoke the initialization of your main app, the rest of your classes will be loaded. I would just compare showing a `Window` with the MANIFEST.MF splash. The performance should not be too different.

Answer (score 0):

Use threading to pause for some time. 
Use the following code in run():

```
try{
  Thread.sleep(4000) // where 4000 is milliseconds
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Add the above code inside the run method with separate try catch block.